# Store escaped HTML in an attribute value

Tags: html, escaping

How can I store escaped HTML in an attribute value?  If I try to store e.g. `&gt;` or `&lt;` in an attribute value on a div, then try to read it back, the browser is unescaping it.

E.g.

HTML

```
<div id="content" tooltip="Ref: &lt;Unknown&gt;">one fine day in the middle of the night...</div>
<button id="show-tooltip">Show tooltip</button>
```

JS

```
var content = document.getElementById('content');
var show = document.getElementById('show-tooltip');
var tooltip;
show.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    if (tooltip) { 
        document.body.removeChild(tooltip);
    }

    tooltip = document.createElement('div');
    tooltip.classList.add('tooltip');
    tooltip.innerHTML = content.getAttribute('tooltip');
    tooltip = document.body.appendChild(tooltip);
});
```

CSS

```
.tooltip {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, .3);    
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/axo25vhy/

I want the tooltip text to display `"Ref: <Unknown>"`, however the text `<Unknown>` is being converted to an HTML tag so does not appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to encode the ampersand in `&lt;` as `&amp;` => `&amp;lt;`

http://jsfiddle.net/etoz8o0x/

When your content is appended to the html, the browser decodes `&amp;` to `<`. If you encode `&amp;` correctly as `&amp;lt;`, the browser decodes `&lt;` which will then presented visually as a `<`

Comment: Of course! Why didn't I think of that! :-) thanks chaenu